# JavaScript: Operators Precedence

Tags: javascript

In this code snippet from **Kyle Simpson's YDKJS books series**:

```
var str = "hello world";
var matches;
if (str && (matches = str.match( /[aeiou]/g ))) {
    // ..
}
```

He argued the necessity of () saying:

> We said the ( ) around the assignment is required, but why? Because &&
>   has higher precedence than =, so without the ( ) to force the binding,
>   the expression would instead be treated as (str && matches) =
>   str.match... But this would be an error, because the result of (str &&
>   matches) isn't going to be a variable, but instead a value (in this
>   case undefined), and so it can't be the left-hand side of an =
>   assignment!

While this sounds reasonable but if the `(str && matches)` would return *undefined* and in JavaScript we can overwrite the undefined's value like in `undefined = true;` unless you are running in strict mode .

So we can say our code snippet without the ( ) around the assignment operation would end in somehow like this :

```
var str = "hello world";
var matches;
// undefined is the result of ( str && matches )
if ( undefined = str.match( /[aeiou]/g ) ) {
    // ..
}
```

But this code works and doesn't throw an error in none-strict mode although and also in none-strict mode our code snippet would throw a `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment` in case of removing the ( ) from around the assignment operation like this :

```
var str = "hello world";
var matches;
if ( str && matches = str.match( /[aeiou]/g ) ) {
    // ..
}
```

So how exactly JavaScript treats this operation `str && matches = str.match( /[aeiou]/g )` ? if as **Kyle Simpson** has said and it will execute ( str && matches ) first which returns *undefined* in our case, Then why the engine throw an error although the ability of overwriting the value of *undefined* in js ?

Comment: I'm getting that error on very legacy versions of node that don't default to strict mode, are you sure that it works? How are you testing it?

Comment: You cannot overwrite undefined in current JS (you can shadow it). In earlier JS, you would need to overwrite `window.undefined`, the property, which would be an lvalue. As Kyle sais, simply `undefined` is just an expression evaluating to a value, and cannot be assigned to.

Comment: @Darkhogg this code works in chrome console

var str = "hello world";
var matches;
// undefined is the result of ( str && matches )
if ( undefined = str.match( /[aeiou]/g ) ) {
    // ..
}

Comment: To add a bit, you don't overwrite undefined the value, but create a variable named undefined.